# Override a Method from a Stateless Spring Service with Additional Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to improve the structure of some code I wrote. I want to override a method of a service, but need another parameter/object for the new functionality. In plain Java, I would solve this by making the needed object an attribute of the class and initialized in the constructor. But because this is a bean, the constructor has no arguments.

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestService extends AbstractService {
    @Override
    public String perform(String original) {
        return original + extra; //<-- What's the best way to get
                                 //    'extra' here from the controller
                                 //    without going stateful?
    }
}

######

public abstract class AbstractService {
    public String perform(String original);
}
```

I think my problem is best described by the code and comments above. How would I get the object to be accessible from that method without adding attributes to the class?

I'm very new to Spring, so feel free to tell me I'm way off track.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: Why not just refactor and add an additional argument to the method in AbstractService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're way off track. Beans can (and should) have constructor arguments for all the classes they depend on.

You should put @Autowired or @Inject before the constructor method which will make spring inject it's parameters from the beans that it knows about. Of course, you'll have to make this 'extra' object a spring bean too.

Answer (score 1):

Bean can have constructor argument and the values can be injected into constructor using constructor dependency injection.
[example](http://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring)

If the extra value is just a property you can inject the value from the property file using @Value or @Autowire Environment and get the value form it.
[example](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)